# GDP Growth QoQ vs YoY: Why do the figures not match?

Tags: gdp, united-states

According to [statista.com](https://www.statista.com/statistics/188185/percent-chance-from-preceding-period-in-real-gdp-in-the-us/), US Q4 GDP growth rate was 2.6% over the economy in Q3. However, why is the annualized growth rate for the US therefore not be a sum of all 4 quarters if their definition of QoQ growth is basically how much the economy grew over the previous quarter? i.e. why is according to statista, the GDP growth of the US in 2018-19 only 2.9%, and not 2.6 + 3.4 + 4.2 + 2.2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because those data are Seasonally adjusted annual rate: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seasonally_adjusted_annual_rate
[image: From 'more information tab']

Comment: So the chart shows growth rate for that quarter, seasonally adjusted, multiplied by 4?

Comment: Yes, it's like such grow would have continued for the whole year. And 2.9 is the real year grow and it's close to the averege of the quarterly gains: (2.6 + 3.4 + 4.2 + 2.2)/4 = 3.1

Answer (score 0):

*Annualized* growth rate does not mean the same as *annual* growth rate.

An *annual* growth rate looks at YoY. A *quarterly* growth rate looks at QoQ.

The *annualized* growth rate takes the *quarterly* growth rate and raises it to the *fourth power*. Essentially, the *annualized* figure is saying "if the economy maintains the same current quarterly growth for the coming three quarters, we will have an *annual* growth rate of this number."